# Decrease variable with each repetition of a for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to get the value of `stack_ypos` to decrease by 50 each time the loop repeats

```
def test_cards():
    for i in range(5):
        card_red(stack4_xpos, stack_ypos)
        stack_ypos - 50

test_cards()
```

It doesn't seem to do anything though.

Comment: You need to assign the value back to the variable: `stack_ypos = stack_ypos - 50`.

Comment: stack_ypos = stack_ypos - 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign the value back to the variable to save it either by doing `stack_ypos = stack_ypos-50` or by `stack_ypos -= 50`. Python has whats called assignment operators which allows you to perform the assingment and the math function by just typing the equals sign and the math function you want next to each other. You can read more about it [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/#assignment-operators)

Answer (score 3):

You don't assign the change in value so your variable does not change!

```
def test_cards():
    for i in range(5):
        card_red(stack4_xpos, stack_ypos)
        stack_ypos -= 50 # equivalent to stack_ypos = stack_ypos - 50

test_cards()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stack_ypos = stack_ypos - 50 #this is how you decrement a variable in most languages including python
```